# static implicit operator for integer

Tags: c#, .net, implicit-conversion

I have created a custom class to hold a integer value read from custom configuration written in application configuration file, it handles integer value perfectly but there is one problem when I set this custom class value to an object type variable it assign whole object to variable instead of its value. Following is the code that I have written.

Please help me how I can get only the value in object type variable instead of whole object of custom integer class.

```
public class IntValueElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("value")]
    public int? Value
    {
        get
        {
            int result;
            if (int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(base["value"]), out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator int?(IntValueElement dt)
    {
        return dt.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(IntValueElement dt)
    {
        if (dt.Value.HasValue)
        {
            return dt.Value.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public class CommonConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("companyID")]
    public IntValueElement CompanyID
    {
        get { return (IntValueElement)base["companyID"]; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartProcess();
    }

    private static void StartProcess()
    {
        CommonConfig cc = AppConfigReader.GetCommonSettings();

        int compayID = cc.CompanyID;  // perfectly set the company id (an integer value read from app config file) in compayID variable;
        int? compayID2 = cc.CompanyID; // perfectly set the company id (an integer value read from app config file) in compayID2 variable;
        object companyID3 = cc.CompanyID; // here it does not set the company id an integer value in compayID3 variable, instead it set the whole IntValueElement object in companyID3 variable;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will only work if you explicitly cast it

```
object companyID3 = (int?)cc.CompanyID;
object companyID4 = (int)cc.CompanyID;
```

that is because all types derive from `object` so the implicit operator is not applied when assigning to a base type.

> user-defined conversion to or from a base class are not allowed.

Documentation: [Using Conversion Operators (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx)

Comment: thanks @Nkosi, I know casting is one of the way, but I was curious to know is there any other way ..

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a value to a variable of a completely different type without an explicit cast, the program will look for the first implicit casting that works for the target type. With `int` and `int?`, your class defines implicit conversions for those types, so the program will use those.

For `object`, though, there is no conversion necessary, since your `IntValueElement` type (and consequently every other type) derives from `object`. In this case, it is merely inheritance, not an implicit cast, so the program isn't going to go looking for a casting option. (And incidentally, as Nkosi points out in his answer, you *can't* define an implicit cast from a type to a base type for this very reason.)

If you want the program to cast your value when assigning to an `object` variable, you have to make it explicit:

```
object companyID3 = (int)cc.CompanyID;
    // OR
object companyID3 = (int?)cc.CompanyID;
```

Comment: If you don't mind can you provide me the link or how do I use explicit operator for my scenario. I have tried with explicit but did not get success.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta Define "did not get success".

Comment: this code I added in IntValueElement Class         public static explicit operator object(IntValueElement dt) 
        {
            return (int)dt;
        }  but it gives compiler error "user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed"

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta Both mine and Nkosi say that exact operation is not allowed. You can't define conversion operators for a base class, and `object` is every class's base class.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. actually I thought that you have written in your comment "you have to make it explicit:"  so my assumption was that it still possible by using "explicit operator" that I had already tried :)

Comment: Is there any way to prompt an compile time error message when some one directly assign CompanyID like this  object companyID3 = cc.CompanyID;  without casting so developer has to cast it explicitly.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta No, because like I said, that is inheritance. You can't prevent an object being assigned to a variable of a base type.